# shell script to read property in an array from property file

Tags: linux, shell, sh

conf.properties file have contents like this:

```
src1=abc
dest1=xyz

src2=123
dest2=456

...
```

The below shell script is accessing the src and dest properties from conf.properties file.

```
. /tmp/conf.properties

echo "$src1"
echo "$dest1"

echo "$src2"
echo "$dest2"
```

Now, there could be any number of src and dest properties in the file.

How to write a code to read all the src and dest from the property file into an array.

Comment: how would you do it? please provide some of your thoughts.

Comment: What shell are you using? POSIX shell does not require array support, and syntax may vary between shells that *do* support arrays.

Comment: fedorqui - I was looking for some inbuilt function that will do it. However, now I think I've to write some logic such as Ajay mentioned in the Answer.

Comment: chepner - I am using bin/sh in the header. So, it is POSIX shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created my own logic after getting clue from Ajay's Answer:

```
filename=/tmp/conf.properties

srcArr=($(grep "src" $filename)) 
destArr=($(grep "dest" $filename))

len=${#srcArr[@]}

for (( i=0; i<${len}; i++ ))
do
    srcVal=$(cut -d"=" -f2 <<< ${srcArr[i]})
    destVal=$(cut -d"=" -f2 <<< ${destArr[i]})

...

done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read and put them separately in two variables.
Read the file line by line keep on appending the src thing in srcVal , seperated by  space.

`set -A srcArrVar -- $srcVal
 set -A destArrVar -- $destVal`
Or you can use associate arry like below

```
typeset -A srcArray
srcArray[src1]="abc"
srcArray[dest1]="xyz"
```

Yes you will need to parse the it .. I can immediately think of one way as below

```
grep "src" filename > srcFile
grep "dest" filename > destFile
sort srcFile > sortedSrcFile
sort destFile > sorteddestFile
srcVal=`cut -d"=" -f2 sortedSrcFile`
destVal=`cut -d"=" -f2 sorteddestFile`
set -A srcArrVar -- $srcVal
set -A destArrVar -- $destVal
```

There can be more elegant way of doing above thing by using sed/awk... and I have assumed that you have no missing values the series is continuous src1,src2... similarly dest1,dest2,dest3....

Comment: But, in this way, I need to parse String in each line to get the value. For example, first line is src1=abc. Then I need to write logic to check whether the String starts with src. and then extract the value "abc" and add it to array.

Comment: `set -A` is specific to `ksh`.

Comment: @chepner Yes you are right, I work on ksh so got ahead with that think it will also work on sh ... my bad

Comment: The code is creating files because of output redirection. I have modified your logic mentioned in the Answer part.